# multiple RewriteCond or multiple RewriteRules, which is more efficient?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What would be more efficient? Having a single `RewriteRule` with an `[OR]` list of `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=8[3-9]$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=9[0-2]$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=35$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /go-here/? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Or multiple `RewriteRules`, each with a single `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=8[3-9]$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /go-here/? [L,R=301,NC]    

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=9[0-2]$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /go-here/? [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=35$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /go-here/? [L,R=301,NC]
```

I'm leaning toward the first option as there are less lines, but perhaps because the argument is more complex the efficiency is lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing you'll notice if you turn on the rewrite logging is that the pattern in a `RewriteRule` gets applied **first**, then if that pattern matches the URI, the `RewriteCond` conditions are checked. That means for the first option, you're matching always, 4 times. However, in the second option, at best, you're matching 2 times and at worst, you're matching 6 times.

So it really depends, at least using the metric of the number of matches required, on how often you expect the query strings to be. If `id=83` happens a *lot*, then the second option may be better. If all id's happen just about the same, then the first option may be best.

The other thing you should consider is the readability of the rules. If you end up having a ton of `RewriteCond`/`RewriteRule` pairs like in the second option, it may be more difficult to read and as you tweak/add/remove rules, you may end up causing problems.

Finally, you probably just want this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(35|8[3-9]|9[0-2])$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /go-here/? [L,R=301,NC]
```

But I'm assuming you've chosen those condition to illustrate the question, and that it's not a real world case.